# Xamarin Forms iOS method for screen size is changed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, size, screen

In my Xamrin.Forms app i used this method for get the screen resolution: I wrote an interface with height and width properties and in the iOS rendere I used UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height and UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width. And it was ok... until about one month ago! Now, if I run my app on iPhone 5c (screen resolution declared 1136x640) the values are 568x320 whit scale 2 and if I run it on iPhone 6 (resolution declared 1334x750) the values are the same, 568x320 whit scale 2!

Does anybody know what is changed?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Density of screen in iOS and Universal WIndows App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489532/density-of-screen-in-ios-and-universal-windows-app)

Comment: The solution you mentioned is my original solution, but in this moment it doesn't work. Better, it works, but I received the same values for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6

Answer (score 0):

No need to use dependency service to get device width & height.

Best way to get screen width & height, whenever screen height or width changes  or screen is rotated **OnSizeAllocated()** will get fired and you will get new width & height

**sample code :**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ABC
{
    public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        private double _width;
        private double _height;

        public MyPage()
        {
            Content = new Label {
                Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            };
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
            _width = width;
            _height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JayPatel for your reply, but your seggestion doesn't resolve my problem. On iPhone 5C and on iPhone 6 the method OnSizeAllocated return the same values: 320 x 568